# 'Vertical' titles for rows on multiple ternary diagram plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, ggtern

I'm trying to plot titles for rows and columns of a multi-plot figure using `ggtern` and `ggplot2`.  I've tried using `theme()` but cannot find attributes that will label the rows properly and displace the text (after rotating it using `angle`).  I would ideally like the rows to have vertical text saying 'Side title: 1' and 'Side title 2'.

This code is from [an example](http://www.ggtern.com/2016/01/17/ggtern-2-0-now-available/) on the ggtern website.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(ggtern)
data(Feldspar)

arrangement = list()

for(r in seq(1,2)){
    for(c in seq(1, 2)){

    title <- ""
    if (r == 1){title <- paste("Top title:", c)}

    ytitle <- ""
    if (c == 1){ ytitle <- paste("Side title:", r)}

      x = ggtern(data=Feldspar,aes(x = Ab,y = An,z = Or)) +
        geom_point() + 
        ggtitle(title)+
        labs(y = ytitle)

      arrangement[[length(arrangement) + 1]] = x
      }
}
grid.arrange(grobs = arrangement)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are meaning to achieve, should be done using faceting via `facet_grid(...)`, such as the following trivial example:

```
library(ggtern)
set.seed(1) #for reproducability
df = data.frame(A=runif(100),B=runif(100),C=runif(100),
                COLS=paste("Column",sample(1:2,100,replace=TRUE)),
                ROWS=paste("Row",   sample(1:2,100,replace=TRUE)))
ggtern(data=df,aes(A,B,C)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(ROWS~COLS)
```

Which produces the following:

[image: example]